# How to use Perl to perform substitutions based on calculations?

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I'm trying to write a perl script to search through a text file, find all decimal numbers, and modify them by some scaling factor.  So far, I have succeeded in extracting the numbers with regular expressions:

```
open(INPUT, $inputPath) or die "$inputPath cannot be opened.";

while ($thisLine = <INPUT>) {
  while ($thisLine =~ m/(-*\d+\.\d+)/g) {
    if(defined($1)) { 
      $new = $scalingFactor*$1;
      print $new."\n";
    }
  }
}

close (INPUT);
```

However, I haven't yet figured out how to reinsert the new values into the file.  I tried using `s/(-*\d+.\d+)/$scalingFactor*$1/g` for substitution, but of course this inserted the string representation of `$scalingFactor` instead of evaluating the expression.

I'm a perl newbie, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance,

-Dan

**Edit:** Solution (based on Roman's Reply)

```
while ($thisLine = <INPUT>) {
  $thisLine =~ s/(-*\d+\.\d+)/$scalingFactor*$1/ge;
  prinf OUTPUT $thisLine;
}
```

Alternatively, Sean's solution also worked great for me.  Thanks all!

Comment: **General remark**:Use three argument [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) like,`open(my $fh, '<', "input.txt") or die $!`;

Comment: @Nikhil Jain Thanks, I'll change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s/(-*\d+.\d+)/$scalingFactor*$1/ge
```

(notice `e` in the end)

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to be correctly modifying the number, but unfortunately it is also causing an infinite loop wherein the number is scaled over and over.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Dan: try escaping the dot in your regexp, i.e. `s/(-*\d+\.\d+)/$scalingFactor*$1/ge`.

Comment: Thanks, leaving the dot unescaped was definitely an error.  This doesn't seem to be responsible for the infinite loop, however.  Basically, whenever multiplication by `$scalingFactor` results in a whole number, the loop terminates.  But whenever the result has a decimal remainder, then it gets scaled again.

Comment: @Dan: could you post a complete example (including a sample input)? I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Dan: ah, so it is your inner `while` loop which loops forever. Can't you just drop it? `g` flag for substitution already ensures that you'll replace all the occurrences.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a self-contained subroutine that'll do the job.  It uses the special variable `$^I`, which activates Perl's in-place editing feature.  (See the "perlvar" man page for more information on `$^I`, and the "perlrun" man page for information about the `-i` command-line switch, which turns on in-place editing.)

```
use strict;  # Always.

sub scale_numbers_in_file_by_factor {
    my ($path, $scaling_factor) = @_;
    local @ARGV = ($path);
    local $^I = '.bak';
    while (<>) {
        s/ ( -? \d+ \. \d+ ) / $scaling_factor * $1 /gex;
        print;
    }
}

scale_numbers_in_file_by_factor('my-file.txt', .1);
```

A backup file will be made by appending `'.bak'` to the original filename.  Change the `'.bak'` to `''` above if you don't want a backup.

You might want to tweak your number-recognizing regular expression.  As written, it will not match numbers without a trailing decimal point and at least one digit.  I think you also want `-?` to match an optional minus sign, not `-*`, which will match any number of minus signs.  Performing arithmetic on a string with more than one leading minus sign will almost certainly not do what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try this out.  You are also certainly right that the `-*` should be changed to `-?`.